# undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-shopping-cart

I'm getting this error while using the [acts-as-shopping-cart gem](https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart):

> ```
> undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass  Extracted source (around line #5):
>
> 2:
> 3: <%= render :partial => 'shopping_cart_item', :collection => @shopping_cart.shopping_cart_items %>
> 4:
> 5:  SubTotal:<%= number_to_currency @shopping_cart.subtotal %>
> 6:  Taxes:<%= number_to_currency @shopping_cart.taxes %>
> 7:  Total:<%= number_to_currency @shopping_cart.total %>
> ```

The fields appear to be defined in the gem source.

#### show.html.erb

```
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

<%= render :partial => 'shopping_cart_item', :collection => @shopping_cart.shopping_cart_items %>

<div><b>SubTotal:</b><%= number_to_currency @shopping_cart.subtotal %></div>
<div><b>Taxes:</b><%= number_to_currency @shopping_cart.taxes %></div>
<div><b>Total:</b><%= number_to_currency @shopping_cart.total %></div>
```

#### shopping_cart.rb

```
class ShoppingCart < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_shopping_cart

  def tax_pct
    8.25
  end

  def taxes
    (subtotal - 10) * tax_pct
  end

end
```

application trace

> app/views/shopping_carts/show.html.erb:5:in
>   `_app_views_shopping_carts_show_html_erb__2338506009803118188_70153042369260'

shopping_carts.controller

```
class ShoppingCartsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :extract_shopping_cart

  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @shopping_cart.add(@product, @product.price)
    redirect_to shopping_cart_path
  end

  def show

  end

  private
  def extract_shopping_cart
    shopping_cart_id = session[:shopping_cart_id]
    @shopping_cart = session[:shopping_cart_id] ? ShoppingCart.find(shopping_cart_id) : ShoppingCart.create
    session[:shopping_cart_id] = @shopping_cart.id
  end
end
```

my repo

https://github.com/atbyrd/Bootstrapped_Devise

Comment: Is there a stack trace to go with that exception? Which `*` is causing  the problem?

Comment: @muistooshort There is only one in the posted code .. and that's [very likely] not the culprit :(

Comment: @pst: Yeah, I'd expect that to complain about `NilClass` not understanding `-` first so the interesting parts aren't in the question at all.

Comment: @muistooshort I update the post with the full error

Comment: Is `@shopping_cart.subtotal` coming out as `nil`? Perhaps `number_to_currency` is trying to multiply internally.

Comment: @muistooshort it appears that all three fields are evaluating as nil. It still fails after removing number_to_currency

Comment: Are you sure that `@shopping_cart` is what you're expecting it to be? `@shopping_cart.taxes` shouldn't be `nil`, it should raise an exception if `@shopping_cart.subtotal.nil?`. Are there missing migrations perhaps?

Comment: Please show the controller code that sets `@shopping_cart`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant posted above, thanks

Comment: @muistooshort I have all the migrations that are in the sample app. Above is a the repo for my app

Comment: Have you tried playing around with this thing in the console? Getting some layers out of the way might make the problem obvious or at least easier to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem only occurs when you add an **unpriced item** to the shopping cart.

So you need to make sure that all products have a price, possibly use a validation, maybe use a before_save function, but make sure that all products have a price and this problem will disappear.

**ps** don't forget to purge any unpriced products from your db before testing this out

Comment: This looks right.  The error suggests the problem is on line 5, where the only thing being evaluated is `@shopping_cart.subtotal`.  If you look at the implementation for subtotal, you see it iterates through the items in the cart and does `item.price * item.quantity`.  This suggests that some `item.price` is `nil`.